# versioncode error while uploading file on PlayStore

Tags: android-studio, ionic3

we are using ionic3 framework for building mobile apps. we are getting the following error while uploading apk to the playstore.

```
Upload failed: 
You need to use a different version code for your APK because you already have one with version code 98.
```

currently we have the following versioncode and versionname in playstore

```
android:versionCode = "8" 
android:versionName = "1.9"
```

But if we try change android:versionCode to 9 and android:versionName to 2.0 , we are getting the above error.

### AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="9" android:versionName="2.0" package="com.global.upi.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, you have already uploaded a version with `versionCode=98` so you'll need to upload a version with `versionCode=99` at least.

`versionName` should not matter much as far as uploading goes.

Comment: versioncode i have changed only '9' but it is appending 8 at the end

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the `android:versionCode = "8"` notation. If you're using Android Studio and gradle, the versionCode is usually defined in `build.gradle` without the `android:` prefix

Comment: thanks mbonnin..we are using android studio and changing the version code inside androidmanifest file